# Referencing two tables for another table in SQL running in Python

Tags: python, sql

Like the title says, I'm trying to reference two tables and combine them partially into a third table. Here's the code.

```
mport sqlite3 as db
connection = db.connect("doctor_who_database")

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS doctor_who_database(
item_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
item TEXT)""")

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS doctor_who_database2(
person_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
season TEXT,
person TEXT)""")

cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO doctor_who_database VALUES ('1', 'Sonic   Screwdriver')""")
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO doctor_who_database VALUES ('2', 'Sonic Cane')""")
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO doctor_who_database VALUES ('3', 'Sonic Sunglasses')""")
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO doctor_who_database VALUES ('4', 'Sonic Probe')""")
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO doctor_who_database VALUES ('5', 'Sonice Gun')""")
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO doctor_who_database VALUES ('6', '3D glasses')""")
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO doctor_who_database2 VALUES ('1', '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9', 'The Doctor All; River Song')""")
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO doctor_who_database2 VALUES ('2', '6', 'The Doctor 11')""")
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO doctor_who_database2 VALUES ('3', '9', 'The Doctor 12')""")
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO doctor_who_database2 VALUES ('4', '6', 'Amy Pond')""")
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO doctor_who_database2 VALUES ('5', '1', 'The Doctor 9; Jack Harkness')""")
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO doctor_who_database2 VALUES ('6', '2', 'The Doctor 10')""")

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS doctor_who_database3(
id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
item TEXT,
season TEXT,
person TEXT)""")

FOREIGN KEY(item) REFERENCES doctor_who_database(item),
```

I'm going to add more references, but I'm trying to figure out the syntax for them, as the python editor/SQL editor says there's a syntax error and I'm not sure what's wrong

Comment: Odd table names... Why two different tables with very similar names?

Comment: first you have to put `FOREIGN KEY(item) REFERENCES doctor_who_database(item),` **inside** the string of the final `cursor.execute`